# all external hardware stops working randomly and windows freezes

Tags: windows-10, memory, freeze, bsod, hardware-failure

recently i built a new rig and i get this **weird freeze very randomly**, while playing games, watching youtube videos, browsing, or using any other applications, **when it freezes all external hardware such as keyboard, mouse, any usb component would stop working** but anything ongoing on pc will continue working, such as if im playing a video during freeze then video will keep going on with some stutter or some times smoothly, same with games or any applications, some times windows will popup alerts saying unrecognized usb device and realtek sound manager will popupt alerts saying sound devices attached detached repeatedly..and please note that have to do hard reset everytime this happens, and it shuts down on pressing power button (but every time different BSOD message will come before shutting down , CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED, STORE_EXCEPTION (don't remember full error name), about six or seven different kinds of BSOD have appeared when shutting down during this freez period)

**What i have tried**

Memtest86+ (Pass, 0 Errors)

Aida64 System Stability Test (No problem there)

FurMark Gpu Stress Test (again no problem)

CPUID Cpu Stress Test / Prime65 CPU Stress over two instances (temp only 62c on 100% load after 10 minutes)

Changed PSU

Changed Ram Slot Twice

**PC CONFIG**

AMD FX8350 8 Core Processor

Kingston HyperX Fury 8 GB  DDR3 1866Mhz Ram

GIgabyte GA-970A-DS3P rev.2 latest bios FD

Kingston SSDNOW 120 GB SSD

WD BLUE 1TB HDD

ASUS AMD R7 240 Graphics Card

WINDOWS 10 64 BIT **(also tried windows 7 64 bit, and windows 8.1 64bit, same problems)**

Corsair 650W PSU / **also tried other PSU with same and lower wattage.**

**TEMPERATURES**

CPU 28c IDLE / **Average 55-60 on Load**

SYSTEM TEMP 44c idle, 55c load

**GPU 38c Idle / 71c load**

Hardware monitor
ITE IT8620

```
Voltage 0       0.90 Volts [0x4B] (CPU VCORE)

Voltage 1       1.48 Volts [0x7B] (DRAM)

Voltage 2       5.16 Volts [0xAC] (+5V)

Voltage 3       12.38 Volts [0xAC] (+12V)

Voltage 4       1.93 Volts [0xA1] (VIN4)

Voltage 5       1.21 Volts [0x65] (VIN5)

Voltage 6       2.22 Volts [0xB9] (VIN6)

Voltage 7       1.63 Volts [0x88] (VIN7)

Voltage 8       1.54 Volts [0x80] (VBAT)

Temperature 0       45°C (113°F) [0x2D] (System)

Temperature 1       46°C (114°F) [0x2E] (CPU)

Temperature 2       25°C (77°F) [0x19] (TMPIN2)

Fan 0           4655 RPM [0x91] (CPU)
```

AMD ADL (Graphics Temps)

```
Voltage 0       0.80 Volts [0x320] (VIN0)

Temperature 0       47°C (116°F) [0x2F] (TMPIN0)

Clock Speed 0       300.00 MHz [0x12C] (Graphics)

Clock Speed 1       300.00 MHz [0x12C] (Memory)
```

Comment: Have you made sure everything is seated correctly inside the computer(Check all power connections, make sure the graphics card is in all the way, etc)? do you have the most recent drivers installed?

Comment: @TheStarvingGeek yes i have latest crimson drivers installed for graphics card, all the drivers updated countless times, all the slots are fitted properly, assembled everything a couple times...

Answer (score 0):

I've been following this issue for some time in the last 3 days as I have also ran into this issue as well on Windows 10, I now have a strong reason to believe that the recent Windows 10 updates may be the cause. The update known as KB3156421 seems to be the culprit, after uninstalling this update I haven't seen the issue happen again on my main machine.

Comment: have tried windows 7, and fresh install of windows 10 without updates...but problem remains..

Comment: also checked the mentioned update is not installed on the system, closest one i could find was KB3156387...will uninstall this and check again...thanx..